# SQL query relating how many of each collection set a given consumer has

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Say I have customers who can be awarded certain prizes:

```
SELECT gs.claimed_by AS consumer_id, p.prize_id AS prize_id FROM 
  awarded_prizes
```

And right now, customer 1 has three prizes and customer 2 has a single prize

```
+-------------+----------+
| consumer_id | prize_id |
+-------------+----------+
|           1 |       45 |
|           1 |       46 |
|           1 |       47 |
|           2 |       66 |
+-------------+----------+
```

Say we also have collections, and if you collect all the members to that collectible, you now have a collectable set:

```
SELECT set_id, member_prize_id AS prize_id FROM collectable_set_members;
+--------+----------+
| set_id | prize_id |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |       45 |
|      1 |       46 |
|      1 |       47 |
|      2 |       65 |
|      2 |       66 |
+--------+----------+
```

With the above table and the previous query, we can see customer 1 has completed set 1 once (they have 45, 46, 47) and customer 2 has completed nothing.

There are cases where a customer can complete a set multiple times (customer could have 45, 46, 47, 45, 46, 47 in the awarded_prize table.

I've been looking at the [pantry problem](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=90) and its variations (like the bartender problem), have been playing with cross joins and groupings and can't seem to find what I want.

I'm trying to get a result for a given customer, showing all the set_ids they own and the number of sets they've completed:

```
+-------------+---------------+--------+
| consumer_id | completed_set |  count |
+-------------+---------------+--------+
|           1 |             1 |      1 |
+-------------+---------------+--------+
```

I'm on mariadb:5.5

Comment: how would you define *complete set*?

Comment: That’s defined in collectable_set_members

Comment: What about overlapping sets?  You made the problem much harder by allowing a customer to complete a set multiple times.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfe458)

My tables have different names than yours, but it proves the point:

```
select sets_x_consumers.consumer_id, sets_x_consumers.set_id, 
  set_summary.items_in_set = consumer_summary.items_per_set_per_consumer as set_is_complete
from (
  -- build a cross-product of sets and consumers
  select distinct set_id, consumer_id
  from sets join consumers -- no join condition -> cross product
) sets_x_consumers 
inner join
( -- the total number of items in each set per set_id
  select set_id, count(*) items_in_set
  from sets 
  group by set_id
) set_summary on sets_x_consumers.set_id = set_summary.set_id
inner join
( -- the total number of items per set and customer 
  select set_id, consumer_id, count(*) items_per_set_per_consumer
  from sets 
  inner join consumers on sets.prize_id = consumers.prize_id
  group by consumer_id, set_id
) consumer_summary on sets_x_consumers.set_id = consumer_summary.set_id and sets_x_consumers.consumer_id = consumer_summary.set_id
```

My basic idea is to sum up the number of items in each set and the number of items per set each consumer has claimed. As long as there are no duplicate entries for the pair of consumer and prize, this should work (if duplicates were allowed, I would use `count distinct(prize_id)` for the `consumer_summary`).

The output of the query above is:

```
| consumer_id | set_id | set_is_complete |
|-------------|--------|-----------------|
|           1 |      1 |               1 |
|           2 |      2 |               0 |
```

This lists each pair of consumers and set for which a consumer has at least one prize. (to change this to list every consumer-set combination, use `outer join`)

Listing only complete sets or summarizing the number of complete sets should be easy on this basis ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Can't really figure out what your last column 'count' is supposed to mean,
but here is a solution that lists users and their sets completed.

[demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61c7b/18)

The whole idea is to count the number of prizes required for each set, and count the collected prizes per customer per set, and thus you can join the two.

I know it's mssql, but I did not manage to make mysql ctes work in sqfiddle.
CTE-s is nothing more than a subquery basically. If your server does not support CTE-s you could use normal subqueries or temp tables instead.

Comment: The "Count" (I assume) is the count of completed sets, grouped by customerid in your example. Have a +1 for getting 90% of the way there on a confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I came up with a nice routine for this in Sql Server.  This works even if there are overlapping prize_id values in each set (will default to higher setid if ambiguous). Assume all temp tables are original data:

```
declare @awarded_prize table (rowid int identity, consumer_id int, prize_id int )
insert @awarded_prize
select * from #awarded_prizes

declare @collections table ( set_id int, prize_id int, rownumber int , filled int)
insert @collections
select *, row_number() over(partition by set_id order by set_id, prize_id) , null
from #collections

declare @todelete table (rowid int)
declare @scorecard table (consumer_id int, set_id int)

declare @iterator int=1
declare @prize_id int
declare @set_id int = (Select min(set_id) from @collections)
declare @consumer_id int = (Select min(consumer_id) from @awarded_prize)
while @consumer_id<=(select max(consumer_id) from @awarded_prize)
    begin
    while @set_id<=(select max(set_id) from @collections)
      begin
        while 1=1
        begin
        select @prize_id=prize_id 
        from @collections 
        where set_id=@set_id and rownumber=@iterator


        if (select max(rowid) from @awarded_prize where prize_id=@prize_id and consumer_id=@consumer_id and rowid not in (select rowid from @todelete)) is null break
        insert @todelete
        select max(rowid) from @awarded_prize where prize_id=@prize_id and consumer_id=@consumer_id and rowid not in (select rowid from @todelete)

        update @collections set filled=1 
        where rownumber=@iterator and set_id=@set_id

        if not exists(select 1 from @collections where set_id=@set_id and filled is null)
        begin
            insert @scorecard
            select @consumer_id, @set_id
            delete @awarded_prize where rowid in (Select rowid from @todelete) 
            delete @todelete
            update @collections set filled=null where filled=1
        end
        set @iterator=case when @iterator=(Select max(rownumber) from @collections where set_id=@set_id) then 
        (select min(rownumber) from @collections where set_id=@set_id) else @iterator+1 end 
      end
      delete @todelete
      set @iterator=1
      set @set_id=@set_id+1
    end
    set @iterator=1
    select @set_id=min(set_id) from @collections
    select @consumer_id=min(consumer_id) from @awarded_prize where consumer_id>@consumer_id
    end

    select consumer_id, set_id, count(*) complete_sets 
    from @scorecard
    group by consumer_id, set_id
    order by consumer_id, set_id
```